# Get a variable from a function using import in python

Tags: python, variables, import

Here is the `main.py` file:

```
from index import count, mainFunction
mainFunction()
print(count)
```

`index.py`:

```
count = 0

def mainFunction():
    global count
    for i in range(10):
        count+=1
```

My problem is that I want to import the `count` variable after the `mainFunction()` has been called. The `count` variable is 0 by default, it gets modified in the `mainFunction()`

Comment: Don't use `from x import y`. Do `import index` and then do `index.count`.